# Securing Web Api for application

Tags: authentication, .net

I have an MVC application that does get/post requests against a separate Web Api. I was wondering what the best method of authentication would be that didn't require any login/refresh request - I had initially thought of just using Basic Authentication however I have read that this isn't supported by .net core.

Basically I'm trying to figure out the best way to limit the web api so it can only be accessed by the MVC application.

Comment: Have you considered OAuth 2 password credential grants?

Comment: Even with Basic Authentication, it is possible for someone to CSRF as the username/password maybe cached in the browser(because it has to be reused for all API requests).

Comment: Are you making client-side requests, or only server-to-server?